# UIButton's Custom image and frame

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have the following code.

```
  UIImage *cancelImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.jpeg"]; 
  UIButton *btnCancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  btnCancel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  [btnCancel setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, 28.0, 28.0)];
  [btnCancel setImage:cancelImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  cell.accessoryView  = btnCancel;
```

cancel.jpeg currently is bigger than 28 x 28 and it's actually 100 x 100.

Why does the button display 100 x 100 size of the image when I've set the UIButton's size to 28 x 28?

Comment: I had to resize the image to 28 x 28.  I just thought that UIButton's frame would cram the 100 x 100 image to 28 x 28.  Guess not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `image` of the button will not be rescaled. Set as the `backgroundImage` if you need rescaling.

```
[btnCancel setBackgroundImage:cancelImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour must have changed since, because the above code produces a scaled down button on iOS 4.2.

Comment: Dang. I actually wanted the behaviour from the original post. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting in iOS 5 with custom buttons that autoresize when the device orientation changes.  I set both a backgroundImage and an image, with the same initial bounds as the button, and what I see is that the backgroundImage resizes and the image does not, but remains centered in the button's frame.